# php mysqli session to check active user status

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to make login page and check if the user is active or not

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = '';
require ( 'conn.php' );
$username = trim( $_POST['username'] );
$password = trim( $_POST['password'] );

$username = $koneksi->escape_string($username);
$password = $koneksi->escape_string($password);

$sql = "SELECT nama, role, status FROM users 
        WHERE username='$username' 
        AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";

$query = $koneksi->query($sql);

if( !$query )
{
    die( 'Oops!! Database gagal '. $koneksi->error );
}

if( $query->num_rows == 0 )
{
$error="Username atau password salah!";
}

if( $query->num_rows == 1 )
{   
    $row =$query->fetch_assoc();

    $_SESSION['nama_user'] = $row['nama']; 
    $_SESSION['akses']     = $row['role'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    if($status == 'Tidak Aktif')
    {
    $error = 'ID anda sudah dinon-aktifkan'; 
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'admin')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_admin']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'guru')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_guru']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'siswa')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_siswasmp']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
    else  
    {
    # jika data yang dimaksud tidak ada
    $error = 'Username atau Password salah'; 
    }
}

if( !empty($error) )
{
$_SESSION['error'] = $error;
header('location:'.$url.'/index.php');
exit();
}
?>
```

everything is working as intended except when the non-active user tried to log-in it returns an error like this on the browser

This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

so any suggestion or fix to optimize this? thanks before

edit :

```
if( $query->num_rows == 1 )
{   
    $row =$query->fetch_assoc();

    $_SESSION['nama_user'] = $row['nama']; 
    $_SESSION['akses']     = $row['role'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    if($status == 'Tidak Aktif')
    {
    $error = 'ID anda sudah dinon-aktifkan';
    unset($_SESSION['akses']);
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'admin' && $row['status']=='Aktif')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_admin']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'guru' && $row['status']=='Aktif')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_guru']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
    else if( $row['role'] == 'siswa' && $row['status']=='Aktif')
    {
    $_SESSION['saya_siswasmp']= 'TRUE';
    header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses'].'/index.php');
    exit;
    }
}
```

unsetting the session if error occurs for akses fixed the problem.  because of this code on index.php

```
if( isset($_SESSION['akses']) )
{
header('location:'.$_SESSION['akses']);
exit();
}
```

Comment: Yes: you should check whether `$_SESSION` already holds an error before redirecting

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're never actually defining `$url` so your redirect actually reads `header('location: /index.php');` ... and if *this* file is index.php that's just going to be an infinite loop - hence the error.

Comment: $url    = 'http://localhost/skripsi2'; i define it at conn.php

Answer (score 0):

Just check the session in the first if

```
if( $query->num_rows == 1 && !isset($_SESSION['nama_user']) )
```

If it's not set means that it's the first time, otherwise it will skip the redirection rules

NB I put "name_user" but you can create a session variable "isLogged".

Answer (score -1):

With each redirect, you redirect to the same redirect. Of cause browsers dont allow endless redirects to the same code that ever ends with the same result. Print an error to the user or only start the code on post or something else.